# memcpy causes segfault after strstr succeeds

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, buffer

I attempted to make a function that takes any URL as input and strips the http:// from it and then takes the uri and the domain from the remainder of the URL. When I execute the code below, I receive a segmentation fault right at the memcpy statement as labelled as "//seg fault here".

Upon execution, I receive the following output:

```
TEST
http:// found
Segmentation fault
```

I expected the following:

```
TEST
http:// found
/ found
www.x.com /a/b/c
```

Why do I receive a segmentation fault when I declared a large buffer space to copy the result to? Is there something in my program that's causing an invalid pointer to result?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getdomurl(const char* in,char* uri,char* dom){
    char b[200000],*p=strstr(in,"http://");
    if (p){
        printf("http:// found\n");
        memcpy(b,p+7,100000); //seg fault here
    }else{
        printf("http:// not found\n");
        memcpy(b,in,100000);
    }
    printf("/ scan\n");
    p=strstr(b,"/");
    if (p){
        printf("/ found\n");
        memcpy(dom,b,p-b);memcpy(uri,p,100000);
    }else{
        printf("/ not found\n");
        memcpy(dom,b,100000);uri[0]='/';uri[1]='\0';
    }
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
char uri[100000];char dom[10000];
printf("TEST\n");
getdomurl("http://www.x.com/a/b/c",uri,dom);
printf("%s %s",uri,dom);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have clearly allocated enough memory for the array b, your input string may not have 100,000 bytes. The way to fix this is to use a function which looks for a null terminating character, strmcpy, instead of memcpy.
  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

```
strncpy(b,p+7,200000);
```

Replace the other 3 uses of memcpy as well.

Comment: Or better yet, use strncpy to avoid overflowing the destination buffer.

Comment: Good Idea, I changed it to use strncpy

Comment: that does work which is why I accept it but I wish there was a good memcpy solution or a solution that doesn't slow down the program

Comment: Both the strncpy and strstr look for terminating characters which takes time, but not much it just iterates through the string. If you really need to increase the speed of this algorithm, there are OS specific functions for finding the size of an allocated block of memory. Somewhere your OS stores a table of allocated memory blocks, and those lookup functions may be faster for extremely long strings, but you would also have to replace strstr possibly by looking if the first 7 characters match "http://".

Answer (score 0):

`p` is assigned a location within `in`, which contains a string literal much shorter than the 100000 bytes you are asking `memcpy` to copy from.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need for `memcpy()` as this entire job can be done with pointers. Here is a rough sketch up that I made for my own `fetch` utility:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void parseurl(char *argv)
{
    char *host;
    char *type;
    char *page;

    type = host = page = argv;
    if ( (host = strstr(argv, "://")))
    {
        *host = '\0';
        host += 3;
    }
    else    
        return;
    if ((page = strstr(host, "/")))
        *page++ = '\0';

    printf("Attempting an [%s] protocol on [%s] to retrieve [%s]\n", type, host, page);
    /* fetch(type, host, page); */
    return;
}

/* "driver" */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    if ( argc != 2 )
        return 1;
    parseurl(*++argv);
    return 0;
}
```

It can be ran as follows:

```
./parseurl http://www.google.com/index.html
```